Question about isomorphisms between vector spaces
Sorry if this post is hard to read because I didn't use latex notation.
I don't know how to use it.
This post assumes AoC.
I opened a new question because I thought it would be better this way that to start asking question in the comments of an 11 year old answered question.
I took a look at this question: Are the groups $(\mathbb{C},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R},+)$ isomorphic?
First of all, I'll assert the following:
let (K,+,.) be a field, and (V,+), (W,+) be 2 vector spaces over K with bases B1 and B2 respectively.
let 0v and 0w be the identity elements of the groups (V,+) and (W,+), i.e. the 0 vectors of each space.
Then V and W are isomorphic as vector spaces iff they have the same dimension.
I'll use the definition that a basis for a vector space is a linearly independent spanning set.
I'll use the definition that 2 sets have the same cardinality iff there exists a bijection between them.
I will put a proof of this at the bottom of the post, as to not clutter the question.
This fact is used is the question I linked.
However, it the answer of that question, there are other assertions that I think are false.
Further, when the cardinality of V is greater than the cardinality of K, the dimension of V is equal to the cardinality of V.
This seems wrong. (Z/2Z,+,.) is a field of cardinality 2. ((Z/2Z)^n,+) is a vector space over (Z/2Z,+,.) of dimension n, but of cardinality 2^n. In fact, any finite vector space of dimension n over a finite field with q elements has q^n elements.
It is also asserted that:
Q is a one-dimensional Q-vector space whereas Q[i] is a two-dimensional Q-vector space, so their additive groups are not isomorphic.
This argument seems wrong. (R,+) and (C,+) are vector spaces over (R,+,.) of dimensions 1 and 2 respectively, yet they are also vector spaces over (Q,+,.).
In the linked question, it is claimed that they are both of the same dimension over Q, the dimension of the continuum. this would make, (R,+) and (C,+) both isomorphic and not isomorphic.
Intuitively, the claim about the dimensions over Q makes sense. I am writing R as a cartesian product of Q with something and C as {1, i}xQx. Assuming the continuum hypotesis, if that something didn't have cardinality of the continuum, then it would be countable, and then R would be countable as the cartesian product of 2 countable sets, by something like Cantor's spiral argument for proving Q is countable, and so would be C.
It also makes intuitive sense why, if R has dimension of the continuum, the C has dimension of the continuum too, as there is a bijection between R and C by the space-filling curves.
I'd still like to see a formal proof of the above.
And with this, I'll ask my questions:
Is there something I'm missing or that is wrong in what I wrote here?
How would you formally prove that R and C have the same dimension over Q, and that the dimension is the dimension of the continuum, if this is true?
How would you prove or disprove that (Q,+) and (Q[i],+) are not isomorphic?
What changes when dealing with modules, especially modules over commutative domains of integrity, like (Z,+,.)?
Are (Q,+) and (Q[i],+) modules over (Z,+,.)? if so, are they then of the same dimension?
If so, does the same reasoning apply? If not, what changes?
I'm not too familiar with modules, so please point out what I'm missing here.
Any interesting facts related to this are welcome, as I'd like to learn more about these things.
Thanks for taking the time to read this long post.
--
Proof:
"=>"
V and W are isomorphic. then there exists a bijection f between them such that
f(X+Y) = f(X) + f(Y) and f(aX) = af(X) for all X and Y in V, for all a in K.
let Y be a vector from W.
By surjectivity, there exists X in V s.t. f(X) = Y
Writing X as a finite linear combination in therms of the basis vectors in B1. and applying the homomorphism property, it shows that Y can be written as a finite linear combination of the vectors in f(B1), hence f(B1) spans W.
f(B1) is linearly independent. A finite linear combination of the vectors in f(B1) is, by the homomorphism property, f evaluated on the same finite linear combination of the vectors in B1. If such a linear combination were equal to 0w, then by the injectivity of f and the fact that f(0v) = 0w we get, by the linear independence of the basis B1, that the above linear combination must be trivial, and as such f(B1) is a linearly independent spanning set, which by definition is a basis for W.
As such, f defines a bijection between a basis for V, B1 and a basis for W, f(B1).
Hence, (V,+) and (W,+) have the same dimension.
"<="
I won't give a full proof of this, mainly because the idea is basically the same as above.
Let f be a bijection between B1 and B2.
Let T be the following map from V to W:
T(X) = f(X), for all X in B1
T(X) = T(a1X1 + a2X2 + ... + anXn) =  a1f(X1) + a2f(X2) + ... + anf(Xn), for all X in V\B1, where X = a1X1 + a2X2 + ... anXn is X expressed as a finite linear combination of the vectors in the basis B2 = f(B1), which exists by the definition of a basis.
To not have any ambiguity is the choice of the linear combination, define T(0v) = 0w, and for the other vectors chose the only finite linear combination that has all coefficients not 0.
The function T is clearly a homomorphism, and proving that it is injective and surjective is not difficult and the arguments are similar to the first part of the proof.
With this, the assertion is proved.

You are saying that two vector spaces over the same field are isomorphic, then changing the base field ON ONLY ONE of them to get them to be non-isomorphic, which doesn't make any sense.

Here is a tutorial on MathJax. It doesn't take a long time to learn it (most of the time we need just a small part of it anyway), so please take a look: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

@Randall Could you please point out where I did that? I said that (C,+) and (R,+) are not isomorphic as spaces over (R,+,.), but, assuming that the dimension of (C,+) over (Q,+,.) is the same as the dimension of (R,+,.), then they are isomorphic as spaces over (Q,+,.). Is that what you were referring too? If so, how should I make it more clear that I'm changing the field for both spaces? A homomorphism between spaces over different fields, as you say, doesn't make sense.

I see that I misread.  I didn't notice that you were forgetting the scalar multiplication and only considering the group structure.

"$\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q[i]$ are not isomorphic because their dimension over the rationals are $1$ and $2$, respectively." is a valid argument. It works because there is a tight connection between the rationals and the integers. Another way to formulate it: In the group $\mathbb Q[i]$, the elements $1$ and $i$ are linearly independent. In the group $\mathbb Q$, any two elements are linearly dependent.

The argument "$\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R[i]$ are not isomorphic because their dimension over the reals are $1$ and $2$, respectively." is invalid. The reals are much larger than the rationals. The tight connection between integers and rationals does not exist between integers and reals.

-1 since the post is mostly unreadable.

For a vector space over $\mathbb Q$, you do not need to be told how the multiplication by a rational number works. It can be completely described in terms of the group structure. E.g., $\frac 23 x$ is the unique element $y$ of the space such that $y + y + y = x + x$. This means that making an abelian group a $\mathbb Q$-vector space is just checking a condition (namely divisibility), not giving additional data. The same is not true for real vector spaces. You will never be able to describe $\sqrt 2 \cdot x$ only in terms of the group structure. In order to understand the vector space, the multiplication has to be known. In other words: A rational vector space is just a special kind of group, a real vector space is more than that.
Here is where this matters in the arguments: $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q[i]$ are indeed non-isomorphic as groups. They are non-isomorphic as rational vector spaces because of their different dimensions. They cannot be isomorphic as groups either, because any isomorphism of groups automatically has to respect the multiplication by rational numbers, since it can be described in terms of the group structure. Every group isomorphism between rational vector spaces is also an isomorphism of vector spaces.
This argument does not work for $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$. They are non-isomorphic as real vector spaces. However, this does not tell us anything about the underlying groups. The groups might be isomorphic, there simply cannot be a group isomorphism that preserves the additional structure that multiplication by $\mathbb R$ provides.
One way to see that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ are isomorphic as rational vector spaces (and also as groups) is the following: Let $(e_j)_{j \in J}$ be a basis for $\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb Q$-vector space. It certainly is not finite, otherwise $\mathbb R \cong \mathbb Q^{\oplus J}$ is a finite product of countable sets, therefore countable. This means that there is a bijective map $b \colon J \to J \times \{1,2\}$. Now for $j \in J$ define $f_{(j,1)} = e_j$ and $f_{(j,2)} = i \cdot e_j$. Then $(f_k)_{k \in J \times \{1,2\}}$ is a $\mathbb Q$-basis of $\mathbb C$. Now define a $\mathbb Q$-linear map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ by sending $e_j$ to $f_{b(j)}$ and extending linearly. This is an isomorphism of $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces.
As for modules over $\mathbb Z$: They are exactly the same thing as abelian groups (multiplication is repeated addition). So $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q[i]$ are $\mathbb Z$-modules and non-isomorphic as such, as seen above. The word "dimension", however, does not apply to modules. Most modules do not admit a basis. Even for those modules that have a basis, there might be several bases of different cardinality (at least in non-commutative world). And in your special case, $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q[i]$ both do not admit bases as $\mathbb Z$-modules. (They are not finitely generated, but any family of two or three elements, respectively, are linearly dependent)

Thanks. By repeating the proof that a function satisfying Cauchy's additive functional equation is a Q-linear map, I was able to prove that a group homomorphism between 2 vector spaces over (Q,+,.) must also be a vector space homomorphism between the 2 spaces. And if such a homomorphism were bijective, then the groups being isomorphic would imply that the spaces were also isomorphic, which is false. Thanks also for the proof that R and C have the same dimension over Q.

The dimensions of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces must at least be infinite (for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are uncountable). AC and basic cardinal arithmetic imply that the dimensions of both these vector spaces must in fact be the cardinality of the continuum (you need AC to exhibit a basis of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, anyways, so we can safely assume we're not working in ZF).
As for why this does not work with $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, it is because every torsion-free, divisible $\mathbb{Z}$-module is a rational vector space; i.e., rational vector spaces are equivalent to torsion-free divisible groups. So if $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are not isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, then they are not isomorphic as abelian groups. However, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, and therefore as abelian groups. Whether they are isomorphic as real vector spaces or not has no bearing on whether they are isomorphic as abelian groups.

Not only is every torsion-free divisible $\mathbb Z$-module a rational vector space, it is a rational vector space in a unique way.
